# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands System.Reflection.PropertyInfo and 'int'

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the piece of code written in c# that I get stuck [Edited]:

```
foreach (var property in this.allProperties)
        {
            var propertyItself = element.GetType().GetProperty(property.GetType().Name);

            if (propertyItself.PropertyType != typeof(Int32))
            { continue; }

            if (propertyType == 0)
            { return false; }
        }
```

If any one is aside of this, could help on giving some information? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to call `GetValue` before evaluating the _value_ of the property.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Why `!(x != y)`? Wouldn't `x == y` be easier to follow?

Comment: @ByteBlast, that sounds pretty obvious which I didnt think about. I'll try it again. Thanks for now!

Comment: And after calling `GetValue`, you'll need to cast the result to `int` in order to get the appropriate comparison...

Comment: @Martin Smith, because I have to skip at some point and thinking in skipping, I wrote that way.

Comment: hello, @devhedgehog! That's a great way to follow. Just trying it right now. Thanks for now! I will comment again if it works!

Comment: @RodCosta Martin is right. not (x not equal to y ) is the same as x equals y

Comment: @devhedgehog, Hm...Yeah, indeed. I edited the code above. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) method before evaluating the *value* of the property like so

```
if (propertyItself == typeof (Int32))
{ 
    if((int) propertyItself.GetValue(element) == 0)
    { 
        return false; 
    }
}
```

You may also consider improving the readability of your expression as I have done above by *only* evaluating that the type equal to an integer.

Comment: and am not sure about this too `var propertyItself = element.GetType().GetProperty(property.GetType().Name);`

Comment: @ByteBlast, After that change, now I'm getting a message as: "No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 'arguments'. What does that mean? What do you think? Even thought this is happening, I think this still being a good approach.

Comment: It means it takes more arguments than you specified.

Comment: The overload of `GetValue` that takes a single argument does exist, but only in .NET 4.5.

Comment: GetValue(element, null)... Try it out.

Comment: @ByteBlast, Yes, of course brother! One more time, thanks! It's accepted. :)